# Arduino cannot receive serial data from blender

Tags: python

I'm trying to send data from blender to arduino(Arduino mega 2560) using pyserial 2.7. But blender cannot send data to Arduino.I'm using COM3 as my serial port and there is no problem with sending data from Arduino to blender.When I'm trying to send data from blender to arduino it print out this error

[image]

My blender code

```
import serial


ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 115200)
var = 10
out = ser.write(var)
```

arduino code

```
int led = 40;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
if (Serial.available())

{

int t= Serial.read();

digitalWrite(led,HIGH);


}
```

Does anyone knows where I'm doing wrong??

Comment: does this work if you test just in the python editor and not in Blender, cause this might not be a Blender issue. If it isn't just Blender I would ask on http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Blender.

Comment: @stacker It's about sending information from **Blender** to Arduino, so it *is* about Blender.  Weather or not it is off-topic is another question.  Personally I don't see any reason why we should close it.

Comment: @PGmath It depends on if the problem is on the blender side of things or not. Of course, it's hard to say where it is, which always makes these tricky.. To me at first glance anyway it looks like the problem isn't in blender so I CVed. If the OP finds out otherwise (e.g. after asking on SO), then the post could be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

The traceback clearly prints:

```
Could not open port 'COM3' PermissionError(13) 'Access is denied'
```

Try to run it as admin.

Comment: Thanks for replying me.. I have tried it using "run as asministrator(windows8)" but it prints out same error..